# What is the difference between vector_name, vector_name.begin() and (vector_name + vector_name.size()), vector_name.end()?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

In this [Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-the-maximum-element-of-a-vector-using-stl-in-c/), they are using  `*max_element(vector_name.begin(), vector_name.end());` while [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/max_element-in-cpp/), they have used `*max_element(vector_name, vector_name + 4);` but when I use `*max_element(vector_name, vector_name.end());` it throws this error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘max_element(std::vector<int>&, std::vector<int>::iterator)’
     max = *max_element(elements, elements.end());
                                                ^
```

Now, I understand that `vector_name` stores the address to vector, whereas `vector_name.begin()` returns an iterator which stores vector address as its value, but I don't understand what exactly is the difference?

Comment: You should pass two pointers (`v, v + 4`) if `v` is array or two iterators (`v.begin(), v.end()`) if `v` is vector. Difference is that you can't dereference a vector (you have iterators for that), but you can dereference a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, `vector_name` is a `std::vector<int>`

- `vector_name.begin()` and `vector_name.end()` returns a `std::vector<int>::iterator` or `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` depending on whether `vector_name` is const-qualified.
- `vector_name + vector_name.size()` is invalid, unless you define an `operator+` for `std::vector<int>` and `std::size_t`.

In second example where they use `*max_element(vector_name, vector_name + 4);`, `vector_name` is a raw array which can be decayed as a pointer to its first element. And `vector_name+4` points to the 5th element (counting the first element as 1st).